# Regularity of solution to heat equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, heat-equation

If $u$ is solution of $u_{t}=\Delta u$ in a bounded domain $\Omega$, is it true that:

1. $\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert=2k}\|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\leq |\Delta^{k}(u^{(l))}\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}=\|u^{(l+k)}\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}$
2. $\|u\|_{H^{2}(\Omega)}\le C \|u_{t}\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$ by elliptic regularity

Comment: I mean, no and no, unless you assume something about the domain and prescribe a boundary condition.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer if i assume that $u=0$ on the boundary of domain $\partial\Omega$ and the domain $\Omega$ is smooth .?